How to hide autocomplete suggestions bar on Android Chrome?
I am attempting to hide the autocomplete bar above the keyboard on Chrome on Android, but all my various attempts are having no impact.
<input type="text"                           
  autocomplete="off" 
  autocorrect="off" 
  autocapitalize="off" 
  spellcheck="false"
  inputmode="text"
  enterkeyhint="next"
/>

JSFiddle demonstrating this: https://jsfiddle.net/38x2s4te/

Tested on Pixel 7, Chrome 130.0.6723.59.
Note: this works perfectly fine on latest iOS Safari and iOS Chrome browsers.
What is the magical incantation (if any) to get this to work?

Just make sure your input is type="password". Your code, to prevent this password from wanting to be saved by Android, must include autocomplete="new-password". This will avoid receiving suggestions regarding the text entered.

Android really wants me to save a password to the Android keychain when I do that. Is there a way to suggest to Android that it shouldn't pop that up in this situation?

Try something like: 

That doesn't seem to work for me

then the only solution is to set a type="password" and change type to "text" when clicking on input

I have that in place too, but unfortunately it still (sometimes?) asks to save the password.
I will file a bug report at the Google Issue Tracker. https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/

as you say, it seems to be a bug rather than a problem in the code
